# How To Update a Line Without Printing a new One in Python?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a progress bar, but I don't want it to print a new line for each character that represents the bar (like: "#"). How do I update the line without printing it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print a `#` without newline with:

```
print('#', end='', flush=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not direct answer to question but just potential suggestion. for many "pretty" terminal formatting i have found `rich` python package to be very useful. for example has progress bar: [link](https://rich.readthedocs.io/en/stable/progress.html) see example of what looks like in gif under progress bar section of [readme](https://github.com/Textualize/rich/tree/master)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the end of line character to nothing.

```
print("#", end =''', flush=True )
```